# What are the pros and cons on Encryption at rest and client side encryption in DynamoDb tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kms

I have the following two design choices for a dynamodb table

1. Using Encryption at Rest
2. Using Client Side Encryption with a AWS KMS managed key

So far from the research I did Encryption at Rest is easier to manage and debug since it will have the data in plain text in console where as if you use client side encryption, you have to do an extra step of decrypting these information before viewing for debugging purposes. What are the other advantages of Encryption at Rest over Client Side Encryption?

What will provide the most efficient performance among the two?
If you were given a choice to select one, which you would choose and why?

Answer (score 2):

1. DynamoDb tables are **always** [encrypted at rest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EncryptionAtRest.html). You **can't** disable it.

   > Server-side encryption at rest is enabled on all DynamoDB table data and cannot be disabled.
2. Second one is up to you. For some **regulatory** reasons you may require encryption of your items which are stored in DynamoDb. If its not required, your life will be much easier without this. Otherwise every single application that writes/reads your items will need to keep encrypting and decrypting the items before they can do anything. It will only cost you in KMS charges, makes development and maintenance of your applications more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB encryption client[1] owner here. :)

As with so many things, which option is best for you depends on your use-case and security (or compliance) requirements.

If server-side encryption satisfies those requirements, then yes, that is the simplest answer and will require the least complexity on your end. You cannot turn off DynamoDB server-side encryption, but you do need to decide how much control you want over the KMS CMK that DynamoDB uses to protect your table[2].

There are some capabilities that client-side encryption offers that server-side does not. Some scenarios where client-side encryption can help you include:

- You have a security or compliance requirement that all data is encrypted locally before it is sent to any service.
- You have items in your table that need to be encrypted under different master keys. For example, if you have a multi-tenant table and you encrypt each customer's data under a customer-specific CMK.
- You have different security requirements for different item attributes. For example, if you have some attributes that are not secret and some that are, and it would be useful to be able to have some portions of your service or application able to read the non-secret attributes but not the secret attributes. In this scenario, you could configure the DynamoDB encryption client to only sign those attributes rather than encrypting and signing them, letting you retain the item integrity check while leaving those non-secret attributes readable to components that cannot decrypt the secret attributes.

There are also some costs to client-side encryption.

- Increased code complexity. If you are working in Java or Python, the DynamoDB encryption client can address a lot of the complexity for you, but using it is still more complex than not doing client-side encryption.
- Increased KMS costs (assuming you're using KMS). This can be reduced using the "most recent provider"[3]; the DynamoDB encryption client's answer to data key reuse.
- Decreased console visibility. As far as DynamoDB is concerned, if you are doing client-side encryption then your items are just data that happen to have an unusually high percentage of Binary attributes, so the console cannot show you the plaintext of your client-side-encrypted attributes.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb-encryption-client/latest/devguide/what-is-ddb-encrypt.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EncryptionAtRest.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb-encryption-client/latest/devguide/most-recent-provider.html